# Plot time series using different colours based on factor

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'd like to plot a single line which is multi-coloured, and the colours are based on the corresponding value in a factor. For instance, a time series of daily stock close price, where the days it has gone up by more than a certain amount are in blue, and the days it has gone done by a lot are in red, and the other days it is in boring black.

My data is in an `xts` object (with the factor put in there with `as.numeric(myfactor)`), and I'd like to be using the quantmod `chartSeries` or `chart_Series` functions. But if that is impossible then something using `plot` would be enough.

Some sample data:

```
library(xts)
x = xts( data.frame( v=(rnorm(50)+10)*10, type=floor(runif(50)*4) ),
  order.by=as.Date("2001-01-01")+1:50)
```

And I can plot it like this:

```
library(quantmod)
chartSeries(x$v)
addTA(x$type, type='p')
```

Which looks like this:
[image: plot using chartSeries]

I.e. I felt it'd be easier to match the information in the bottom chart with the top one if coloured line segments were being used.

Comment: You should post some data.I'm guessin you don't want what most people would call a "line" but rather want colored "segments".

Comment: @BondedDust I've added some test data. `segments` might be what I want, though it seems quite low level (no support for timestamps on the x-axis?)

Answer (score 2):

So here's a `ggplot` solution. It's a bit more involved, but offers more sophisticated formatting options.

```
library(quantmod)
sp500 <- getSymbols("^GSPC", from="2015-01-01", auto.assign=FALSE)
sp500 <- Cl(sp500)                         # extract close
sp500 <- merge(sp500, dailyReturn(sp500))  # add daily returns
sp500 <- merge(lag(Cl(sp500),1), sp500)    # merge with close lagged by 1 day

names(sp500) <- c("ymin", "ymax", "return")
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
df <- with(sp500,
           data.frame(xmin=c(lag(index(sp500),1)),
                      xmax=index(sp500), 
                      ymin, ymax, return))
df$status <- with(df,ifelse(return>0.01,"up",ifelse(return< -0.01,"down","neutral")))
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=xmin, xend=xmax, y=ymin, yend=ymax, color=status)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c(up="green", down="red", neutral="grey50"), 
                     breaks=c("up","down"),
                     labels=c("Gain > 1%", "Loss > 1%")) +
  scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("months"), labels=date_format("%b"))+
  labs(x=NULL, y="Closing Price", title="S&P 500") +
  theme(panel.background =element_rect(fill="black"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

As with the other answer the basic idea is to draw segments color coded based on the magnitude of the gain/loss. So we start by extracting closing prices, add a column of returns, and then add another column of closing prices lagged by 1 day. Then we create a data.frame from this with two columns of dates, also lagged by 1 day. Then we add a column (`status`) to indicate if the gain/loss was > 1%. Then we use this to drive `geom_segment(...)`, color coding by `status`. In the `scale_color_manual(...)` call, we set the colors to red and green, and exclude the neutral color from the legend. The rest is all formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This code started out as a minor mod of the example code on `?segments` and that is why the title of the graph looks odd ,but I decided to leave it in anyway. The logic is that the terms inside the "[.]" will "pick" colors based on the difference between successive values formed as the difference between `tail(y,-1)` and `head(y,-1)`, with the default being "black" and the the thresholds being 1 in this case, but that could easily be changed:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- 1:12; y <- rnorm(12)
plot(x, y, main = "arrows(.) and segments(.)")

s <- seq(length(x)-1)  
arrows(x[s], y[s], x[s+1], y[s+1], 
       col= c("black", "red", "blue")[1+                          # default=1
                                       (tail(y,-1)-head(y,-1) < -1) + # big down (1+1)
                                     2*(tail(y,-1)-head(y,-1) > 1) ] ) # big up (1+2)
```

If you just wanted boring line segments you can use the `segments` function rather than  `arrows`.

[image]

I realize on reading the question once again that you said you already had a factor variable in your xts-object, although my understanding is that xts-objects might not be capable of holding factor-type columns, since they are elaborations of the zoo-class and the coredata is an R matrix (hence no level attributes). But perhaps the quant-guys have a workaround for that? So that would be yet another reason for you to post some data, and PLEASE do use `dput` for presenting the object. Building xts-objects from console output is a real hassle.